# Can a WPF UserControl be marked as obsolete?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, user-controls

I'm writing a new version of a central UserControl in a collection of controls. I want to set the old version to obsolete so the developers won't use it anymore (and hopefully change the old references as well).

I've tried setting the codebehind class to obsolete, but this doesn't seem to have any effect. Is there any other way - in XAML or code - to tell the compiler to warn about an obsolete UserControl?

EDIT: To clarify, I want the warning to show when the UserControl is referenced in XAML. If it's instantiated in codebehind, and the codebehind class is marked as obsolete, the warning will show.

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting when you mark an old version as obsolete? Resharper (at least) will highlight any references to classes with an obsolete attribute along with the comment. This would seem, at first glance, to fit the bill. If you compile with treat warnings as errors option (recommended) then unless that warning has been explicitly excluded it will break the build. Not sure if that is what you want.

So, if you use the attribute ObsoleteAttribute the compiler will definitely warn about obsolete classes. But, in my opinion, warning are not much use unless they fail the build.

Rob

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, but I want the studio/compiler to show a warning in the error list when the UserControl is referenced. A UserControl reference in XAML does not seem to be handled the same as a class reference in code, as I - as I wrote - already tried marking the codebehind class as obsolete, with no result. Bringing ReSharper an user settings into the picture doesn't really solve my problem, as it's out of my hands.